# dynamically positioning 120x600 ads in side for ajax call and scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

in my page I am loading content dynamically on scroll I want to show 120x600 ads in side bar and with this code I can do this, but the problem is it goes to the top if I use fixed or absolute.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 6%; left: 0%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;"><iframe src="http://www.xxxxx.com/ads/160.html" width="170" height="600" frameborder="1"></iframe></br>
</div>
```

if I use the relative position it shows and its scrollable also this is what I want but it comes inside the already loaded content but I want it to go to the extreme end as I am giving left 0 % but it considers that 0% from already loaded main content which has margin of 200 px . I tried overflow=visible and negative margin and z index even but it does not work .
any advise will be great

Answer (score 1):

solved this question with top: initial;